# Duplicate symbols between Facebook SDK and AWS v2

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, linker-errors, facebook-sdk-4.0, linker-flags

I am getting crazy of these errors. It's been hours I am fighting it with no luck. How can I solve this thing?

I have `-all_load` linker flag. Tried changing to `-force_load` and got "ld: file not found: -fobjc-arc".

Please help.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._sourceURL in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._targets in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._webURL in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLink.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLink.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLink._isBackToReferrer in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._extras in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkNavigation.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkNavigation._appLinkData in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._attachedToNavController in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._lastShownUrl in:
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._lastShownBFUrl in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController._delegate in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererController.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._includeStatusBarInSize in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._labelView in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView._closeButton in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_BFAppLinkReturnToRefererView in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(Bolts.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(Bolts.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Bolts in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(EXTRuntimeExtensions.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(EXTRuntimeExtensions.o)
duplicate symbol _mtl_executeCleanupBlock in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(EXTScope.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(EXTScope.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLJSONAdapter._modelClass in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLJSONAdapter._JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLJSONAdapter._model in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLJSONAdapter in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTLJSONAdapter in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLJSONAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLManagedObjectAdapter._modelClass in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLManagedObjectAdapter._managedObjectKeysByPropertyKey in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLManagedObjectAdapter._relationshipModelClassesByPropertyKey in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLManagedObjectAdapter in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLManagedObjectAdapter.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTLManagedObjectAdapter in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLModel.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLModel.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTLModel in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLModel.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLModel.o)
duplicate symbol _MTLSelectorWithKeyPattern in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLReflection.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLReflection.o)
duplicate symbol _MTLSelectorWithCapitalizedKeyPattern in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLReflection.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLReflection.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLValueTransformer._forwardBlock in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLValueTransformer.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLValueTransformer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MTLValueTransformer._reverseBlock in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLValueTransformer.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLValueTransformer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MTLReversibleValueTransformer in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLValueTransformer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MTLValueTransformer in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(MTLValueTransformer.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(MTLValueTransformer.o)
duplicate symbol _aws_loadMTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(NSValueTransformer+MTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(NSValueTransformer+MTLPredefinedTransformerAdditions.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods_Mantle in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(Pods-Mantle-dummy.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(Pods-Mantle-dummy.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods_Mantle in:
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/Mantle.framework/Mantle(Pods-Mantle-dummy.o)
    /Users/nathangurfnkel/Desktop/iOS Projects/Pounce/iPhone/AWSiOSSDKv2.framework/AWSiOSSDKv2(Pods-Mantle-dummy.o)
ld: 131 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make sure you are using the latest versions of the Facebook and AWS SDK. Both of them have Bolts.framework. You should include the one in the Facebook SDK, and do not import the one in the AWS SDK. Please note that when you remove a framework, you should double check `Framework Search Paths` doesn't point to the framework you've just removed.